# Troubleshooting: Integration of SSL certificate into Postfix

Tags: postfix, tls

In order to use TLS on my Postfix server, I have used directly the nginx ssl files from my other server, which also uses the domain that I want to use with postfix.

I have integrated the files in the follwing way into main.cf:

```
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/subdomain.example.com.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/subdomain.example.com.key
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/subdomain.example.com.pem
```

I haven't done something with openssl or something, I just used the files that I use for my another server in nginx. But this shouldn't be a problem I guess, because the mail server uses also the same domain as nginx.

Sending a mail with postfix via shell (`mail`) is not a problem at all, but when I want to use my postfix server as a relay server I get the following error (sceanrio: I want to use my smtp server in a PHP-CMS):

```
cannot enable STARTTLS, though 'subdomain.example.com:25' advertised it:
4.7.0 TLS           not available due to local problem (454)
```

mail.log:

```
Feb  5 15:40:09 koto postfix/smtpd[8911]: warning: TLS library problem: error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:bss_file.c:172:
Feb  5 15:40:09 koto postfix/smtpd[8911]: warning: TLS library problem: error:0B084002:x509 certificate routines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib:by_file.c:274:
```

My main.cf:

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version


# Debian specific:  Specifying a file name will cause the first
# line of that file to be used as the name.  The Debian default
# is /etc/mailname.
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/subdomain.example.com.crt
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/subdomain.example.com.key
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/subdomain.example.com.pem

smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Debian/GNU)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache


# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = debian-512mb-fra1-01
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = **domain**, debian-512mb-fra1-01, localhost.localdomain, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_command = procmail -a "$EXTENSION"
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

mime_header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks
header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks

smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = *****
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
header_size_limit = 4096000
relayhost = [smtp.sendgrid.net]:587
```

==> What is the problem here?

Comment: Are you certain that postfix has permissions to access these cert files?

Comment: Yes, tried  `chmod 777 /etc/ssl/*` - and still have the problem.

Comment: @fkin, check this: http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_tls_cert_file. You need to have `smtpd_tls_cert_file'` in pem format.

Comment: Ok, now it is: `smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/subdomain.example.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/subdomain.example.key´, what is with the crt-file?